# How do I setup an network (port 8080) launched on-demand service with launchd

Tags: mac-osx, launchd

I'm trying to run a service in 'ondemand' mode, but I can't even get launchctl to register the service.

```
$ launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.fossil-scm.fossil.plist
bind(): Permission denied
bind(): Permission denied
$
```

As I'm getting a double 'bind' error I believe I've done something wrong with the Sockets configuration in the attached plist.

**How do I setup an network(port 8080) launched on-demand service with launchd?**

The apple dev documentation for launchd/launchctl/launchd.plist, TN2083 Daemons and Agents, and 'Creating launchd Daemons and Agents' is a bit thin on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
 <dict/>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>org.fossil-scm.fossil</string>
 <key>KeepAlive</key>
 <false/>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <false/>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
  <string>/usr/local/fossil/bin/fossil</string>
  <string>http</string>
  <string>/Users/spdegabrielle/fossil-local-repository/myclone.fossil</string>
 </array>
 <key>Sockets</key>
 <dict>
                <key>Listeners</key>
                <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>SockFamily</key>
                        <string>IPv4</string>
                        <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>http-alt</string>
                        <key>SockType</key>
                        <string>stream</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                        <key>SockFamily</key>
                        <string>IPv6</string>
                        <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>http-alt</string>
                        <key>SockType</key>
                        <string>stream</string>
                </dict>
                </array>
        </dict>
 <key>UserName</key>
 <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: UserName was added as I thought perhaps I needed to run is in /Library/LaunchDaemons/, rather than my preferred location ~/Library/LaunchAgents

I'm wanting to associate the launchagent with port 8080, but it seems http-alt expects port 591:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/services |grep http-alt
http-alt    591/udp     # FileMaker, Inc. - HTTP Alternate (see Port 80)
http-alt    591/tcp     # FileMaker, Inc. - HTTP Alternate (see Port 80)
http-alt    8008/udp     # HTTP Alternate
http-alt    8008/tcp     # HTTP Alternate
http-alt    8080/udp     # HTTP Alternate (see port 80)
http-alt    8080/tcp     # HTTP Alternate (see port 80)
```

The default of http-alt using the name is Filemaker (6!), simple change the SockServiceName to 8080 or you port of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you're trying to attach the process to port 591 (http-alt).

In Mac OS X (as any other Unix) a regular user can't attach any process to ports under 1024, only root can do such operations.

Your guess is right, move the plist over to the general dir at in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` (since this is listening in a socket it makes sense for the plist to be there) and `sudo launchctl load` the process

Comment: <code>$ sudo cat /etc/services |grep http-alt
http-alt 591/udp     # FileMaker, Inc. - HTTP Alternate (see Port 80)
http-alt 591/tcp     # FileMaker, Inc. - HTTP Alternate (see Port 80)
http-alt 8008/udp     # HTTP Alternate
http-alt 8008/tcp     # HTTP Alternate
http-alt 8080/udp     # HTTP Alternate (see port 80)
http-alt 8080/tcp     # HTTP Alternate (see port 80)

Comment: damn - I need 8080, not 591.

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you 'answered'! your response is a breakthrough!

Comment: answered - I'll ask a new question.

Comment: Cool! Happy to see it worked